# Custom Hierarchy Error

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

Hello I am relatively new to Salesforce and am trying to create a visualforce Account Hierarchy page that displays more than 500 accounts. I'm receiving this error whenever I test out my link on most accounts except for one and I'm hoping someone can point out what it is I am doing wrong

Error Message:

> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested
>   field: Account.ParentId  An unexpected error has occurred. Your
>   development organization has been notified.

Code:

```
public class LAM_Hierarchy_AP {

    public Account acc { get; private set; }
    public List<Account> accountList { get; private set; }
    public ApexPages.StandardController controller { get; private set; }

    public LAM_Hierarchy_AP(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.acc = (Account)controller.getRecord();
        this.accountList = new List<Account>();

        Account baseAccount = [SELECT Id, ParentId, Parent.Name, LAM_Shipping_Address__c, Name, Type, OPCO__c, Site_ID__c, Rolling_12_Month_Total_Revenue__c,(SELECT Id, Name FROM ChildAccounts)FROM Account WHERE Id = :acc.id LIMIT 1000];
        accountList.add(baseAccount);

        // Traverse the hierarchy downwards
        Set<Id> accountsToQuery = new Map<Id, Account>(baseAccount.ChildAccounts).keySet();
        while (accountsToQuery.size() > 0) {
            List<Account> thisLevelAccounts = [SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, Parent.Name, Type, LAM_Shipping_Address__c, OPCO__c, Site_ID__c, Rolling_12_Month_Total_Revenue__c, 
                                              // (Select Id, Name, Phone, Email from Contacts),
                                               (SELECT Id, Name FROM ChildAccounts)
                                               FROM Account
                                               WHERE Id IN :accountsToQuery LIMIT 1000];

            accountsToQuery = new Set<Id>();

            for (Account a : thisLevelAccounts) {
                // Add this Account (with its Contacts) to the list.
                accountList.add(a);
                //System.debug(a);
                // Add this Account's children to the query for the next level.
                for (Account child : a.ChildAccounts) {
                    if(a.Id == child.ParentId ){
                        accountsToQuery.add(child.Id);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

VFP:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="LAM_Hierarchy_AP">    

        <apex:pageBlock title="{!Account.Name}">

                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! accountList }" var="a" id="conlist" title="Contact">

                        <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" style="align: center;">
                              <apex:outputField value="{!a.Name}" style="width: 150px;"/>
                        </apex:column>    

                        <apex:column headerValue="Record Type" style="align: center;">
                            <apex:outputField value="{!a.Type}" style="width: 150px;"/>
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Rolling 12 Month Total Revenue" style="align: center;">
                            <apex:outputField value="{!a.Rolling_12_Month_Total_Revenue__c}" style="width: 150px;"/>
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="OPCO" style="align: center;">
                            <apex:outputField value="{!a.OPCO__c}" style="width: 150px;"/>
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Site" style="align: center;">
                            <apex:outputField value="{!a.Site_ID__c}" style="width: 150px;"/>
                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column headerValue="Mailing Address" style="align: center;">
                            <apex:outputField value="{!a.LAM_Shipping_Address__c}" style="width: 150px;"/>
                        </apex:column>

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Working with hierarchical data in Salesforce can be quite challenging. There's a fundamental conflict between the recursive nature of collecting the related records, and the SOQL governor limit. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
(SELECT Id, Name FROM ChildAccounts)
```

You need to add `ParentId` to this `SELECT` clause.